# railsのURLの末尾にスラッシュをつけたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

railsでリンクを張るときにurlヘルパーを使って指定しているのですが、パラメータをもたせた時だけ末尾にスラッシュがつかなくて困っています。

`config/application.rb`に以下の設定を加えています。

```
config.action_controller.default_url_options = { :trailing_slash => true }
```

### 理想

`post_detail_path` => `/post/detail/`
`post_detail_path(:id)` => `/post/detail/:id/`

### 現状

`post_detail_path` => `/post/detail/`
`post_detail_path(:id)` => `/post/detail/:id`

パラメータもスラッシュありにしたいのですがどうしたらよいでしょうか。
railsのメソッドを上書きするやり方でも構いませんのでおしえていただけるとたすかります。

Answer (score 1):

こんな記事がありました.

[Railsでトレイリングスラッシュを自動付加](http://www.yefisys.com/blog/2014/01/04/trailing-slash-in-rails/)

application.rb

```
class Application < Rails::Application
  config.action_controller.default_url_options = {trailing_slash: true}
end
```

rails4.1でもできるみたいです.
ただ、記事先の指摘のあったキャッシュの問題についてはわかりません.

当方の環境では、link_toなどのid付きのリンク先もスラッシュ付きに変換されています.
application.rbを書き換えたので、一度サーバーを再起動したらどうでしょうか.